# Command Line: create a link to folder and access files in this folder

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, symlink

I want to do this thing:

- Create a link to a folder.
- Put this link in home (~) directory
- Access files in linked folder from home directory (~/LinkToFolder/file)

What is the best way to it?

Main Problem.
I have a set of scripts, that lay in specific folder in git repository local clone.
I want to access them from home directory in very simple way.

`perl ~/LinkToFolder/myWorkScript.pl param1 param2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with **Symlinks**:

```
ln -s /path/to/original/location /path/to/intended/shortcut
```

For example, if you want ~/Scripts to go to ~/Dropbox/Documents/Scripts you can do…

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/Documents/Scripts ~/Scripts
```

Then `open ~/Scripts/test.sh` will open the file at `~/Dropbox/Documents/Scripts/test.sh`.

To see the symlink you can run `ls -laPGh ~/Scripts`.

For example, I have my Mobile Documents folder symlinked as iCloud, so…

```
ls -lapGh ~/iCloud
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 grgarside  staff    41B 12 Nov  2012 iCloud -> /Users/grgarside/Library/Mobile Documents
```

Comment: good answer, but I want to add, that I must put absolute path as original location :)
Please, add this information to answer

Comment: @gaussblurinc It should work also with relative paths and with ~ (it will be expanded by the shell). Which problem did you have?

Comment: @Matteo I go to my directory and make `ln -s Scripts/ ~/Scripts`. This thing won't work for me, it seems, that symlink doesn't point on original :(

Comment: @gaussblurinc:  `ln -s THE_File_or_DIR_POINTED_AT  The_NEW_SYMLINK`. So `ln -s /path/to/Scripts  ~/Scripts` will create in your homedir a "Scripts" symlink pointing at `/path/to/Scripts` . Do not use "~" elsewhere (ie, in the first parameter, for example) as it's only useable in some conditions, but not always. "~" is only evaluated to your homedir in special (common) cases, but not always.

Comment: @gaussblurinc : not also that `ls -al /the/symlink` will list the symlink itself.  `ls -al /the/symlink/` [note the trailing `/`] will list the content of the directory pointed at. Ie, beware of some special side-effects of using a symlink.